# How to capture only one word from a sentence in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

---

AWESOME :)

Another QUESTION:

What if I have multiple Sentences like:

[PROGRAMMING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (AMB)

[PATCHING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (CCB)

Notice that the last word that I need to take out varies from sentence to sentence. How can i make sure that I always take out the last part of the sentence. In this case; (AMB) and (CCB)

I also need to do the same with the words at the beginning:

[PROGRAMMING]
[PATCHING]

Thanks :)

Comment: More details on your requirement would be nice. What are the other sentences you have? How do each differ?

Comment: Or maybe simpler `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("AMB",A1)),"","AMB")` :)

Comment: The two sentences are added in the new question above ^

Comment: @user3629282 Avoid posting the same question please. Editing was the right choice, but not posting another question with almost the same content. Can you have multiple things wrapped between parentheses in a sentence? Do all your sentences have `Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain`?

Comment: Sorry, the other post was deleted.
I think I can have miltple things wrapped in different parenheses: () []Not all sentences have Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain, let me give you another example:


[PROGRAMMING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (AMB)
[PATCHING]-Suspected NBB-OPENS Domains- 175.132.56.1-hyuft-molb (CCB)

So, I need these words to be taken out from each sentence:

PROGRAMMING-AMB
PATCHING-CCB

Comment: Is the part within `[]` always at the beginning? Is the part in `()` always at the end and always 3 letters long?

Comment: That is correct, all sentences start with [] and end with () always with 3 letters.

Comment: Something else

I need to take out the "abc" from this structure:


MnageTime:             4 July
WANName:          Sustain LKL - PLKJH Plain Domains 
Adrresss:               182.176.255.1
NameCon:          tlcnotgut.abc.port.qwert.com

Note that the abc comes after a bunch of information and it is in last line of NameCon:

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for the part within `[]`:

```
=MID(A2,2,FIND("]",A2)-2)
```

And this for the part within `()`:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,3)
```

[googlespreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-m2bF9p_pHA06fRhqvppLXwg-wu9_vbO4ZNP8M9-n7Q/edit?usp=sharing)

`MID` takes 3 parameters:

1. A text,
2. A starting position,
3. The length of the extracted text.

`FIND` takes 2-3 parameters and returns a position number:

1. Something it will look for,
2. The text in which it will look for the something,
3. The position from where it'll start looking. If not mentioned, looks from the beginning.

`=MID(A2,2,FIND("]",A2)-2)` with your first example becomes the following after replacing the innermost evaluation:

```
=MID(A2,2,FIND("]","[PROGRAMMING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (AMB)")-2)
```

`FIND("]","[PROGRAMMING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (AMB)")`

`]` appears at the 13th position, so this `FIND()` returns `13`. The `MID` becomes:

`=MID(A2,2,13-2)` => `=MID(A2,2,11)`

And if you count the characters in `PROGRAMMING`, there are 11. I removed 2, because 1 is for the beginning `[` to be removed, the second is for the `]` to be removed.

Now, it becomes:

```
=MID("[PROGRAMMING]-Old System-TRT Operates-192.168.6.0-qwert8-plain (AMB)",2,11)
```

Which means start (including) at character 2 and take 11 characters, which gives the text you are looking for.

The one for `()` is just as simple if you got the above.

Comment: Awesome :)

Something else, in case there is no value: how could I add an IFERROR so that all values shown as #VALUE! can instead be shown as "Not Found" lets say.

Comment: @user3629282 Just wrap the whole function: `=IFERROR( FUNCTION(), "Not Found")` in both cases. I updated the spreadsheet above with some example formulae.

Comment: I came up with something.
How would you remove something after a dash? for instance -->
bbc12-molb
try56-screen

I need everything that is after the dash (-) to be removed. 

Thanks,

Comment: @user3629282 Are there two dashes there? And try using `=LEFT()`. It's almost the same as MID but simpler.

Comment: it has only one dash in the middle

Comment: @user3629282 Use LEFT like I mentioned. `=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)`

Comment: Something else I need to take out the "abc" from this structure: 

MnageTime: 4 July WANName: Sustain LKL - PLKJH Plain Domains 
Adrresss: 182.176.255.1 
NameCon: tlcnotgut.abc.port.qwert.com 

Note that the abc comes after a bunch of information and it is in the last line "NameCon"

Comment: +1 for fail-proof technique that takes me right back to 1990, when it would already have worked!

Comment: Basically I need to find extract the "abc" that is in the last line, however that "abc" varies from entry to entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MID() function if the data always follows the same pattern.

`=MID(A1, FIND("(",A1, 1) + 1, LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1, 1)-1)`

Assuming the string is in A1. The first parameter is the string. The second is the start of the substring to extract. You want to start one character past the first parenthesis. The last parameter is the length of the substring to extract. You want to take the whole string minus all the characters before the parenthesis and also ignore the last parenthesis (thus the -1).